# Is there a way to decode octet stream file

Tags: python, data-science, extract, decode, binary-data

I need to extract useful/readable data from the following link in which the file is in .let format

https://physionet.org/content/gaitndd/1.0.0/als13.let

the file types is application/octet stream

please help me with proper data extraction so that I could use it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far? Please provide what you have tried and where you are encountering a specific problem.

Comment: @Saavi there is Chinese content?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi it's a _binary_ file (a part of [Gait in Neurodegenerative Disease Database](https://physionet.org/content/gaitndd/1.0.0/#files-panel). All the database is described in detail there incl. [a visualization tool](https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=gaitndd/1.0.0)…